# Separate displaced items from the original Plane

Tags: mesh

Newbie here trying to learn blender.  I have been following some tutorials on creating 3d maps in blender and have followed them ok.

I have a large plane that has been displaced using a black and white texture image then the map itself applied as a texture image.

The original plane has quite alot of flat area around the 3d map.

When a I go into Edit mode I loose the texture so I have no idea how much I mesh I can remove?

Is it possible to copy only the displaced area of the Plane?

The final idea would be to create a base that I would then place the map on?

[image]

Comment: use a boolean modifier?

Comment: Use the black and white map for alpha